# add a sidebar to the Category archive pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to add a sidebar to the Category, Tag and search results archive pages?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You can add sidebar in this file `archive.php`

Answer (score 2):

> *The Template Hierarchy specifies that WordPress will use the first Template file it finds in your current Theme's directory from the
>   following list:*

***For Category:-***

```
 1. category-slug.php
 2. category-ID.php
 3. category.php
 4. archive.php
 5. index.php
```

***For Tag:-***

```
1. tag-slug.php
2. tag-id.php
3. tag.php
4. archive.php
5. index.php
```

If you don't have one, **use archive.php**, and so on.

***For Search Result:-***

```
 1. search.php
```

This is not a Search Page, it is merely a template that displays the search results.

And add use this below code for sidebar. put below code in file where you want to display sidebar. **This is default sidebar**

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```